# Fast IPv6 CIDR to Number or comaparable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ipv6

I am using geoip database, it was pretty easy to import ipv4 database, CIDR format were converted to range and range to integer.

but i am unable to find any central resource where i can find how to store and search IPv6.

I tried converting IPv6 CIDR to range, searched for libraries

used `ipaddr.js` for conversion for `"2001:240:1000::/36"`  it returned `[ { parts: [ 8193, 576, 4096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] }, 36 ]`, Really no way to convert it to int

bit searching

```
function ip62long($ipv6){
    $ip_n = inet_pton($ipv6);
    $bits = 15;

    $ipv6long = 0;

    while($bits >= 0){
        $bin = sprintf("%08b",(ord($ip_n[$bits])));

        if($ipv6long){
            $ipv6long = $bin . $ipv6long;
        }
        else{
            $ipv6long = $bin;
        }
        $bits--;
    }
    return gmp_strval(gmp_init($ipv6long, 2), 10);
}
```

I am trying to import into  mongodb,

Please guide me how to store and search ipv6 in node js.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has no data-type which is a really good fit for IPv6 addresses. Integers only go up to 64bit, but an IPv6 address is 128bit.

The best workaround might be to store them as strings. IPv6 addresses sort alphabetically when you don't remove the omitted zeros. This means you can express a range by giving minimum and maximum value. The IP range `2001:240:1000::/36` could be expressed as:

`{
    from: "20010240100000000000000000000000",
    to:   "200102401fffffffffffffffffffffff"
}`

To find the range of an IP address like `2001:240:1024::125a:32fd` you would perform this query:

```
db.ipranges.find({
    from: { $lt:"200102401024000000000000125a32fd"}, 
    to: { $gt:"200102401024000000000000125a32fd"}
});
```

However, depending on your use-case, it might be enough to only store the first 64bit of the IP range. In an IPv6 address, the first 64bit are the network prefix and the last 64bit the interface identifier. The interface identifier is either the MAC address of the host or completely random (with privacy extensions). There is no relation between interface identifier and geographical location. That means you won't encounter any GeoIP ranges longer than 64bit. So storing the first 64bit of the IPv6 range as an integer might be enough.

Comment: Actually, no prefixes longer than /48 will be advertised on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, So should i store `2001:218:e001:8000::/49`
as `20010218e0018000` similary end range of subnet, the above is smallest network i?

`2001:208:5::/49` as `2001020800050000` ?

Comment: Better store always all 32 digits, i.e. `20010218e00180000000000000000000`. Otherwise it may fail if you have to work with different prefixes, i.e. different sub-network sizes. If your network prefix (i.e. `/49`) does **never** change, then the short version would be sufficient.